# Use powershell to run an installation from C#

Tags: c#, powershell, failed-installation

The problem is installation shutdown and uninstall the windows service, but stopped and hang in there in the background. If I run the script outside the code, everything works. just wondering if it is possible to call installation this way in the code and how?

The application is running as Windows Service. This service will call a powershell script to run an installation. In the installation, it will shutdown the Windows service and re-install. the code is below:

```
   string filepath = Path.Combine(requiredFiles.First().Value.Path);
        script = $"Start-Process -FilePath {filepath} -ArgumentList \"/S 
        /Q localhost\"";
        _Log.Info($"powershell running: {script}");
        var process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe";
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = script;

        process.Start();
        process.WaitForExit();
```

Thank you very much for your help.
I am pretty sure RunspaceFactory will not work.

Comment: Why would you run PowerShell to run an MSI or similar with a few arguments and not just run that directly?

Comment: Have you tried to debug it?

Comment: @seth you mean start "cmd.exe" and arg is the install.exe? I will try it. thanks

Comment: @montonero, Installation is called in the service while it's running. Since installation kills the service, it's hard to debug why it stops. But once installation uninstalled everything, it supposed to re-install again, but it stopped even thou it's supposed to be in different process. Not know why.

Comment: Why even start cmd if you could just directly call the installation routine with the proper arguments?

Comment: @briswill It seems to me that the installation is showing a message box (with an error presumably) which is not visible due to a run under a System account. What kind of installer you're using?

Comment: @montonero it's our application installation to install application as windows service. If the installation called in cmd or powershell, it worked. If it's call within the service, it will remove the service and stuck in the background. What I am trying to do is to use separate process to call the installation.exe even the service is removed.

Comment: @Seth I tried either way, same thing happened. the EXE just stuck in the background. is it possible to run EXE from c# service even c# service is removed and EXE still runing serparately?

Comment: Currently you're waiting for the execution to end before continuing. Don't do that and your service should be able to continue its execution. Which component does the removal? The service itself or the installation? It probably should be part of the installation.

Comment: @briswill The installer will be a separate process no matter if it'll be run with cmd or not.